# What is the most Efficient way to search a data(string) on MS Access/DataGridView in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

What is the most efficient way to search a data from database/DGV and compare to textbox.text if match variable as Boolean is equal to true

I have a 500 and above number of rows

I use For Next and table adapter filter

```
'adapter filter
Me.StudenttableBindingSource.Filter = "[Card Number] like '" & IDTapTextBox.Text & "'"

'textbox1 is bind to [Card Number]
Dim found As Boolean
if textbox1.text = IDTapTextBox.Text then
found = true
End

'For Next
Dim found As Boolean
            Dim lookfor As String = Student_numberTextBox.Text
            For dgv As Integer = In_TableDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                If In_TableDataGridView.RowCount > 0 Then
                    If lookfor = In_TableDataGridView.Rows(dgv).Cells(0).Value.ToString Then
                        found = True
                    End If
                Else
                    found = False
                End If
    enter code here
            Next
```

Comment: Add the code you have tried and explain what is not meeting your requirements.

Comment: If the data is bound to the grid, search the backing object not the grid... IMHO this is opinion based...

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to a TextBox to search Access?  If so, try this.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    Private bindingSource1 As New BindingSource()
    Private dataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter()

    <STAThreadAttribute()> _
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Application.Run(New Form1())
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\Northwind_2012.mdb"
        Dim selectCommand As String
        Dim connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)

        selectCommand = "Select * From MyExcelTable ORDER BY ID"
        Me.dataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommand, connection)

        With DataGridView1
            .AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells
            .AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.ColumnHeader
            .AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.ColumnHeader
        End With

        Dim commandBuilder As New OleDbCommandBuilder(Me.dataAdapter)
        Dim table As New DataTable()

        table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

        Me.dataAdapter.Fill(table)
        Me.bindingSource1.DataSource = table

        Dim data As New DataSet()

        data.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

        DataGridView1.DataSource = Me.bindingSource1
        Me.DataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Aqua
        Me.DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns( _
            DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, btnUpdate.Click
        Dim table As New DataTable()

        Me.bindingSource1 = Me.DataGridView1.DataSource
        table = Me.bindingSource1.DataSource

        Me.dataAdapter.Update(table)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click, btnClose.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged, TextBox1.Click

        Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\Northwind_2012.mdb"
        Dim selectCommand As String
        Dim connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)

        'selectCommand = "Select * From MyExcelTable where Fname = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
        '"SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Address LIKE '" & strAddressSearch & "%'"
        'or ending with:
        '"SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Address LIKE '%" & strAddressSearch & "'"

        selectCommand = "Select * From MyExcelTable where Fname Like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"
        Me.dataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommand, connection)

        With DataGridView1
            .AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells
            .AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.ColumnHeader
            .AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.ColumnHeader
        End With

        Dim commandBuilder As New OleDbCommandBuilder(Me.dataAdapter)
        Dim table As New DataTable()

        table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

        Me.dataAdapter.Fill(table)
        Me.bindingSource1.DataSource = table

        Dim data As New DataSet()

        data.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

        DataGridView1.DataSource = Me.bindingSource1
        Me.DataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Aqua
        Me.DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns( _
            DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells)

    End Sub
End Class
```

I included some other functionality to read from Access on a FormLoad event and saving results in a DataGridView to Access.  Hope it helps.